# Align images in WPF canvas in center

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I am developing an image viewer based on gestures using Kinect. I am using the following XAML code to display images on a canvas.

```
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" Height="732" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image x:Name="next" Source="{Binding NextPicture}" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="732" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Image x:Name="previous" Source="{Binding PreviousPicture}" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="732" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Image x:Name="current" Source="{Binding Picture}" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="732" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Canvas>
```

This is code that runs in the back:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the previous image displayed.
    /// </summary>
    public BitmapImage PreviousPicture { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current image to be displayed.
    /// </summary>
    public BitmapImage Picture { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the next image displayed.
    /// </summary>
    public BitmapImage NextPicture { get; private set; }
```

Every time a gesture is recognized, the properties are changed as shown:

```
    // Setup corresponding picture if pictures are available.
                this.PreviousPicture = this.Picture;
                this.Picture = this.NextPicture;
                this.NextPicture = LoadPicture(Index + 1);

                // Notify world of change to Index and Picture.
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PreviousPicture"));
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Picture"));
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NextPicture"));
                }
```

The problem however is, the images that I display on the canvas get aligned randomly to the left or right. Also their aspect ratio changes sometimes. What I want is, the images should be displayed on the center of the canvas in their original aspect ratio. Can anyone help me in that regard?

Also, I am able to set the image to the center using the C# code as follows:

```
    Canvas.SetLeft(current, (1249 - current.ActualWidth) / 2);
    Canvas.SetTop(current, 0);
```

where, 'current' is the name of the current image in the XAML code. But I want it to happen automatically. Is it possible in the XAML code? If not, how do I achieve it?

PS: I am not so good at C# or WPF. So please explain in layman terms if possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `Canvas` to contain your controls? A `Grid` would work much better since you could simply set `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` of your images to `Center`.

Comment: @Rachel, Yes. I am actually translating my hand co-ordinates into position relative to the screen and then panning through a zoomed image by setting the 'Canvas.Left' and 'Canvas.Top' properties in my code. I tried using 'Translate Transform' but I could not figure out a way using that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could center the image in the XAML by binding the `Canvas.Left` property using an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) that accepts parameters of your `Canvas.Width` and `Image.Width`, and returns `(Canvas.Width / 2) - (Image.Width / 2)`, however per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710887/align-images-in-wpf-canvas-in-center#comment17162805_12710887) above it sounds like you are allowing users to re-position an image using hand movements by setting `Canvas.Left` of the Image, and this would overwrite your binding with the converter.

I would actually recommend using a `Grid` instead of a `Canvas`, and positioning your image using `HorizontalAlignment=Center`, and allowing users to adjust the image's position by using a `RenderTransform` (Note that you need to use `RenderTransform`, not `LayoutTransform`, so the transformation gets applied at render time, not when WPF is trying to layout your objects).

If that doesn't work, I would change the Picture properties from BitmapImages to an actual class representing that image, with properties for `BitmapImage`, `Top`, and `Left`. To move around images, you would alter the `Picture.Left` property, and when the user switches pictures you can reset the `Picture.Left` property to its original value

Comment: I was making a stupid mistake in using Render Transform. Its working now. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use canvas.  Use a little method when the app starts to determine the center of your screen.  Get the size of the window divide by two and then use that as a start for the position of the Images.  For kinect controling I would definitly use canvas.