# How to place an image by its center, not top-left corner?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an image (inside canvas). I need to specify the coordinates of the image in text box, and I want the image **center** to be in this point (not its top-left corner). How can I do that?

**Update:** I don't need to place my image in the center of the canvas. I want the position of the image to be defined by **image** center. Example, I have a code: `<Image source"..." canvas.Left="0" canvas.Top="0">`, and this point (0,0) means that the image center is in the top-left corner of the canvas.

Comment: Why not set the `RenderTransform` of your image to half it's height/width? Either that, or use a `Converter`. I have a simple [Math Converter](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/tag/math-converter/) posted on my blog that I usually use, and its easy to extend it into a `MultiConverter` that accepts multiple bound values (such as `TextBox.Text` and `Image.Height/Width`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the position using Attached properties:

- Canvas.Left
- Canvas.Top

If you want to place at center, set

```
Canvas.SetLeft(image, (canva.Width - Image.Width) / 2);
Canvas.SetTop(image, (canva.Height- Image.Height) / 2);
```

Also look [Align images in WPF canvas in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710887/align-images-in-wpf-canvas-in-center)

**Update**

```
Canvas.SetLeft(image, Image.Width / 2);
Canvas.SetTop(image, Image.Height / 2);
```

You can set it from behaviors for example

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:wpfSample="clr-namespace:WpfSample"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="800"
        Background="Gray">
    <Border Width="400"
            Height="400"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="2">
        <Canvas >
            <Rectangle Fill="OrangeRed" Width="150" Height="150">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <wpfSample:CenterBehavior/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

and the behavior (raw sample)

```
public class CenterBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        UpdatePosition();
        AssociatedObject.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private void UpdatePosition()
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(AssociatedObject, -AssociatedObject.Width/2);
        Canvas.SetTop(AssociatedObject, -AssociatedObject.Height/2);
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need to place my image in the center of the canvas. I want the position of the image to be **defined** by its center. Example, I have a code: <Image source"..." canvas.Left="0" canvas.Top="0">, and this point (0,0) means that the **image center** is in the top-left corner of the **canvas**.

Comment: just to clarify, you want your image position to be set relatively to canvas center? So if you set Canvas.Left="-12" it means it will be Canvas.Width/2-12?

Comment: This answer is fine and it does what the question asks.  It is useful to split this behavior in two, one that centers only horizontally, and one that centers only vertically. Also, the `ActualHeight` property must be used instead of `Height`. (For example, if you try centering a `TextBlock`, its `Width` and `Height` properties may be `NaN`, but its actual dimensions will be computed from the text it contains.)

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract half of your `Image.Width` value your current `Canvas.Left` value and subtract half of your `Image.Height` value your current `Canvas.Top` value.